# Defining a function of a variable through another intermediate variable

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions, variable

The following is a really simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I have a variable fn defined in terms some other variable x. I then want to define a function of x through the variable fn.

```
fn = x^2;
f[x_] := fn
f[2]
```

However, Mathematica doesn't like it. For f[2] it just spits out $x^2$. How can I make this work? (In my complicated case I really don't want to define a function fn[x_]:=x^2 and then define f[x_]:=fn[x_])

Edit: It has been suggested to use Evaluate@fn. Which indeed works. However, let me propose a different example that doesn't work:

```
fn = x^2 a^2;
f[x_] := NIntegrate[Evaluate@fn, {a, -1, 1}]
f[2]
```

(and similarly if I put Evaluate@NIntegrate instead)

Comment: try `f[x_] := Evaluate@fn` it is because you used delayed assignment. If you used `f[x_] = fn` then it would have worked. But delayed is better in general.  You just need to know the difference between `=` and `:=` in Mathematica. These have different semantics.  ps. this type of question has been asked before few times,. I am sure it is somewhere in [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/137213#137213)

Comment: Thank you @Nasser, see my edit in the question above.

Comment: The only real answer is: you shouldn't be doing this in the first place. Mathematica doesn't like it *for a reason*. In any case you may want to look into [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if we know why you had things set up this way, because it looks like your fighting against the evaluation engine here, but as a workaround, you could do something like this:

```
(* make a legit function *)
f = Function[x, Evaluate[fn]]

(* use it in your integration function *)
fInt[x_] := NIntegrate[f[x], {a, -1, 1}]
```

This forces the `x` to get replaced first when you call `fInt`.